# Why does pddl find the solution incomplete

Tags: pddl

Below is a small part of a river crossing problem written in pddl. I tried to find the solution in two different tools (editor.planning.domains and stripsfiddle.herokuapp.com) but both of them gave the same result.

```
;domain;
(define (domain RiverCrossing)
(:requirements :strips :typing)
(:types 
    Farmer Fox - passengers
)

(:predicates 
     (onLeftBank ?p - passengers)
     (onRightBank ?p - passengers)
)

(:action crossRiverLR
    :parameters (?f - Farmer)
    :precondition (  and (onLeftBank ?f))
    :effect(  and (onRightBank ?f)  )
)
(:action crossRiverRL
    :parameters (?f - Farmer)
    :precondition (  and (onRightBank ?f))
    :effect(  and (onLeftBank ?f)  )
)
(:action crossRiverLRf
    :parameters ( ?fx - Fox ?f - Farmer)
    :precondition (  and (onLeftBank ?f) (onLeftBank ?fx) )
    :effect(  and (onRightBank ?fx) (onRightBank ?f) )
)
(:action crossRiverRLf
    :parameters (?f - Farmer ?fx - Fox)
    :precondition (  and (onRightBank ?f) (onRightBank ?fx) )
    :effect(  and (onLeftBank ?f) (onLeftBank ?fx)  )
)

)
```

Problem

```
(define (problem RCP)
(:domain RiverCrossing)
(:objects
    farmer - Farmer
    fox - Fox
    )

(:init
    (onRightBank farmer) (onLeftBank fox)
)

(:goal 
  (and
    (onLeftBank farmer) (onRightBank fox)
  )
)
)
```

Both of the compilers give the same result; Farmer does not go to LeftBank:

```
Solution found in 2 steps!
1. crossRiverRL farmer

2. crossRiverLRf fox farmer
```

Can anyone help me figure out the point I am missing?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem is not negating the previous situation (OnLeftBank) after setting the next situation (OnRightBank). 
Below is the sample correction which I applied to all effects;

```
(:action crossRiverLR
    :parameters (?f - Farmer)
    :precondition (  and (onLeftBank ?f))
    :effect(  and (onRightBank ?f) 
                  (not (onLefttBank ?f)) ; **** adding this solved the problem. ****
     )
)
```